# Removing vertices coincident with point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, vertices, remove

Is there any way in QGIS to delete vertices in an automatic way from a feature which are coincident with a point layer?

I have many lines forming a "T shape", so I would like to remove the middle vertex of the horizontal line so the only vertex there is the first (or last) one from the vertical line. Every line has a different length, so it's not possible to smooth or simplify the feature.

Comment: If the 'top' of the T is a straight line, then the middle vertex is an unnecessary vertex. You might be able to solve your problem with an 'remove unnecessary vertices' tool.

Comment: The truth is that this could work... Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Extract the vertices of the line and than delete all the vertices that are very close to one of the points. Than re-connect remaining vertices to a line again.

Your line layer needs an attribute with a field containing unique values, in my case `id`. Layer names: `lines` (black line on the screenshot below) and `points` (red dots). Change all these names accordingly. The `overlay_nearest` function is available since QGIS 3.16, see [visual changelog](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core). For older versions, use the [refFunctions plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/).

How you do it:

1. `Menu Vector / Geometry tools / Extract vertices`: white dots
2. On the resulting layer from one, select features using the toolbar icon `select by expression` with this expression. It looks for the nearest feature from the layer `points` and if the distance is smaller than 0.1, it is selected (in fact, distance should be 0 - but to be sure in case of rounding errors, set a minimal distance):

```
distance (
    $geometry, 
    array_first ( 
        overlay_nearest(    
            'points', 
            $geometry
        )
    )
) <0.1
```

3. Delete the selected points (yellow in the screenshot).
4. `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Points to Path` to re-connect the remaining points: for sorting, select the field `vertex_index`, for grouping select `id`. You get the blue line, corresponding to the original, black line, minus the vertexes where your have red dots.

[image]

The result looks like this. Be aware that the topology changes: on the T shape at the right, be deleting the vertex where both lines meet, being in the same time the start point of the vertical line, you loose the first segment and thus, the two lines are no longer connected. This is not a flaw of this solution, but of the very concept of removing certain vertices. So consider very well what effects the operation will have and what you can use the output for (what what not).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the ["Geometry by Expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) tool.

An expression like

```
make_line(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry))
```

will ignore the middle vertex.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I have more vertices in that line that I want to keep, so this solution could be useful if the line is short and has those only three vertices. Thank you!